# Does inductance depend on a bias field?

Tags: electric-circuits, inductance

Considering that the energy $U$ stored in a magnetic field $B$ is scales as $U \propto B^2$.

It is clear that if we have two identical coils (same number of turns, area and length), but with opposing currents of equal magnitude in a strong bias field:

[image]

one will have a more energetic configuration than the other.

On the other hand, the energy stored in an inductor is given by $U = LI^2 / 2$.

This suggests that that $L_{A} \neq L_{B}$. But from experience, I have never seen this effect (in resonant circuits and so), and I am lead to believe that $L_{A} = L_{B}$.

So that's the question, is $L_{A}$ equal to $L_{B}$? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work done to energize an inductor from its state of *zero* current $i=o$  to having current $i=I$ is the integral $W_m=\int_0^I Lidi = \frac{1}{2}LI^2$. If there were no other fields present while changing the current this then is equal to the inductor's magnetic energy: $\mathcal{E}_m =W_m$. This formula says nothing about other possible sources of energy that may be present, i.e., kinetic, potential, or even other magnetic field energies and their interactions. If, for example, what you call bias field $B_0$ is generated by another coil and its current then during the increase of the current from $i=0$ to $i=I$ you are also inducing a current opposing this field (Lenz) through the mutual inductance of the coils. To maintain the biasing field work has to be put in the "biasing" coil and its current source, etc.

Comment: More than answering my question you have rephrased it, please answer: are the inductances the same or different? If you charge both of them from 0 to I, and they both end up in states where the total energy of the system is different, then the inductance for both of them is different, no?

Comment: You are confusing the concepts of inductance with current. Inductance is a material and geometric property of a coil of wire (matter), current is what goes through it driven by an external agency. Energy is the result of the work expended by establishing the current by that agency while the inductance (with *other* magnetic matter present) is a given. If the *other* currents are fixed, that is the bias field is fixed then work is expended to keep them that way by *other* sources meanwhile all the inductances (mutual, too) are given.

Comment: True, the confusion came from the incompleteness of the expression W = 0.5 LI^2, as it has to include the mutual inductance term, which is clearly going to be positive in one case and negative in the other. So the energy and mutual inductance is different but the self inductance is the same.